# How to plot extremely small numbers

Tags: graphing-functions

For example, I have a data set like the below:

Sequence:   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8;
X: 0.5, 0.2e-5  , 0.2e-6, 0.2e-7,  0.2e-8,  0.2e-9,  0.2e-10,  0.2e-11;
Y: 0.6,  0.3e-4,  0.3e-5, 0.3e-6, 0.3e-7, 0.3e-8, 0.3e-9, 0.3e-10.

If I directly plot these data by sequence, we cannot see any difference between X and Y starting from sequence 2 because those numbers are so small.

Are there some plotting methods that can handle such small numbers? For example, I wish the plot has the Y-axis from 1 to 0.2e-12, and the width of Y-axis are the same for 1 to 0.1, 0.1 to 0.01, 0.01 to 0.001, etc. Basically, I hope the Y-axis can have different value magnitude, such that the number difference in small values can be highlighted well.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Make the y axis log scale

Comment: And if that is not enough use the log log scale.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there some plotting methods that can handle such small numbers? For example, I wish the plot has the Y-axis from 1 to 0.2e-12, and the width of Y-axis are the same for 1 to 0.1, 0.1 to 0.01, 0.01 to 0.001, etc.

This is called a [logarithmic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale#Graphic_representation), or log plot, and is extremely common in scientific literature. Most data analysis programs should support this natively.

Answer (score 3):

All the coordinates are positive.

Make a log log plot of the data to include all data.

If you leave out the first point $ (0.5,0.6)$ as already you know how big it is, (log x - log y) zooms to a better plot .. the range/domain scales -5 to -11 in the smaller magnitude region.